# Eclipse headless build of C++ & Java Projects

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, svn

I am performing checkout from SVN which contains both Java & C++ projects. After that I am trying to do headless build using following command:

```
 D:\Path\to\eclipse>eclipsec.exe -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data "D:\path\to\checkout" -build all
```

After running this what I am getting is only :

```
Building All Projects...
Building workspace
```

That's it..Its just creating a `.metadata` folder in the given path `D:\path\to\checkout` and nothing else. What is expected is it should create `.dll` files of `C++` projects, but it does nothing.

How can I achieve proper headless build & how to manage dependencies?

**UPDATE**

So I imported that folder into eclipse(& closed it so that I run it from command line) and ran above command, what it is doing now is building projects but gives error whenever processing a `C++` file:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Exceptions/Exception.h': No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: If you have the project setup as an ant or maven build, why not run that tool directly, instead of running eclipse ?

Comment: @jr593 As of now not using ant/maven.